# Convert text to hyperlink on button click in same textbox?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Good day

I need to convert text within a textbox into a hyperlink.

The thing is, the new link must then be displayed in the textbox.

I'm using a script on google maps to automatically enter the coordinates into the textbox once the user chooses a location on the modal google map popup. When they press "Continue" after they've selected their location, those coordinates must be added after this url: "https://www.google.com/maps/place(+ Coordinates)", which will give the user a link to their location if they require it.

So the coordinates are already filled once they click on the map. After pressing 'continue' it must just add the google maps url before the coordinates, to make a link.

Any help would be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/fag9n52y/105/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#cancel").click(function(){ //closes coor1 class and clears coordinate1 value
     $(".Coor1").hide();
     $("#Coordinate1").val('');
});
  $("#clearFields").click(function (){ // clears Coordinate1 value
     $("#Coordinate1").val('');
  });
});


var center = new google.maps.LatLng(23.578462278048715, 45.40855407714844);
function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: center
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: center
       
    });

   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
      $("#Coordinate1").val(event.latLng.lat() + ", " + event.latLng.lng());
      $("#Coordinate1").select();

         if (marker) { marker.setMap(null); }

                 marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: event.latLng, map: map});
                 map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
                });

}
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#Coordinate1').on('click', function () {
    $('#modal').modal({
        keyboard: false
    }).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        map.setCenter(center);
    });
});
});
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
body, .modal-open .page-container, .modal-open .page-container .navbar-fixed-top, .modal-open .modal-container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
@media (max-width: 979px) {
    .modal-open .page-container .navbar-fixed-top {
        overflow-y: visible;
    }
}
#map-canvas {
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Coordinate1">

<div id="modal" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary" data-value="1">Continue</button> <!-- WHEN THIS BUTTON IS CLICKED, THE COORDINATES WHICH HAVE BEEN AUTOMATICALLY ENTERED INTO THE TEXTBOX, MUST BE CONVERTED INTO A HYPERLINK" -->
        <button type="button" id="clearFields" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Clear</button>
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" id="cancel" class="btn" data-value="0">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code , what you have tried.

Comment: "https://www.google.com/maps/place("+Coordinates+")" 
This forms required link.

Comment: I will post the code now.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way to put a hyperlink in a text field like that. I modified your fiddle a little bit and used a span instead of text field. Text fields are typically user input, so they aren't designed to hold hyperlinks. That being said, you can accomplish a similar effect with a span. Please see modified fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/usrsud21/

I used the following code to create a hyperlink in the span:

```
document.getElementById("Coordinate1").innerHTML="<a href = "+"https://www.google.com/maps/place/"+event.latLng.lat() + "," + event.latLng.lng()+">https://www.google.com/maps/place/"+event.latLng.lat() + "," + event.latLng.lng()+"</a>";
```

I changed the design slightly to make it work. I put a div around the words "launch map" and set it to where clicking "launch map" launches the map. I also changed the text input to a span and put a placeholder of "Maps URL Here." This placeholder will be replaced with a hyperlink as soon as you click the map to create a marker. It will be replaced by a hyperlink going to maps.google.com so that it opens up to the same lat,lng  coordinates as the marker.

I hope this helps!